# inline functions returning incorrect results

Tags: c++, inline, inline-code

I have a large application that I am working on in C++, and we have a class where the inline functions are returning the wrong value. It looks like they are offset by one entry.

Here is an example of how the code is set up:

```
class Test
{

private:
    uint myVal1;    
    uint myVal2;
    uint myVal3;
    uint myVal4;

public:
    uint myFunct1() const { return myVal1 };
    uint myFunct2() const { return myVal2 };
};
```

What we are seeing is that myFunct1 returns myVal2 and myFunct2 returns myVal3. If I dont make the functions inlined everything works as expected.

Any ideas on why this would be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like an uninitialized variable (pointer) (somewhere else in the code) to me..

Comment: let's rule out the really daft stuff, are you really sure the values are set correctly?

Comment: yeah the values are definitely set correctly and its not an uninitialized variable because all of the members look right and like i said if i define these functions inside the .cpp instead of the .h file everything work perfect

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(I assume that what you posted above is actually a fragment from some header file.)

Things like that typically happen when different source files in your program are compiled with different memory-layout-related settings, like class packing and alignment settings. Your header file is included into these different translation units and is interpreted differently because of the discrepancies in memory-layout settings.

Once you start passing your `Test` objects between these translation units, the problem reveals itself. One translation unit creates a `Test` object with one memory layout, then another translation units reads it or writes into it assuming a totally different memory layout. In your case it is your inline functions that get interpreted differently in each translation unit.

If you define your member functions as non-inline ones, they will assume the class memory layout specific to the source file in which they are defined. This will sweep the problem under the carpet and make things "work" (since the access functions are now tied to one memory layout), but nevertheless it is still not a good situation to have. It still can lead to various problems of similar nature down the road.

Make sure all source files in your program are compiled with exactly the same class memory layout settings.

**P.S.** As Fred noted in the comments, the discrepancy in the class memory layout between translation units can be caused by something as prosaic as forgetting to recompile a source file after modifying a header file the source file depends upon.

Another "popular" source of such problems is class definitions that depend on preprocessor directives (i.e. class layout "customized" by `#ifdef`/`#endif` segments). If you forget to `#define` something important in some source file that includes your header file, you might end up with different memory layout for the class in that source file.

Comment: This also happens when you compile a TU, modify a header, compile a second TU, then link the two TUs together (without recompiling the first).  In other words, for both the situation above and for mine, your build system is screwed up.  Make sure you are tracking header dependencies.

Comment: looks like there was an issue with popping the last packing alignment value off correctly

Comment: @JumboSmith- I am having the same issue. How did you resolve it?

Comment: @user1166419: Well, what JumboSmith says is that they had disbalanced push/pop pragmas for alignment settings (i.e. `#pragma pack(push, ...)`/`#pragma pack(pop, ...)` directives). Naturally, they must heave resolved it by fixing the disbalance.

Answer (score 3):

No, inlined functions are (of course) required to have the same results as non-inlined functions. So, the problem must be somewhere else, in the code you are not showing. Perhaps the one magically setting the values of the private members?

Comment: i dont think thats the issue, like i said if i define the function in the .cpp and not .h file, everything works fine.

Comment: @JumboSmith: But that shouldn't make a difference, so the problem must be elsewhere. I would bet AndreyT's answer is a good clue.